# Getting ConcurrentModificationException when running code on hosts

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, concurrency

I am getting ConcurrentModificationException when running the below code in production environments. The issue appear to be an intermittent one (when I try to call the api which uses the below code, it works fine).

I have checked similar questions but in each of them, someone would iterate over a list and modify it at the same time. I am not sure what is the problem with the below code and why does it throw the exception. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
private String getLookupKeyForODPair () {
    
    final List<LookUpKey> lookUpKeyList = transitTimeConfiguration.getLookUpKeys();
    
    // Build lookUpKey
    final String lookUpKey = buildLookupKey(lookUpKeyList, originDestinationPair, merchantId);

    // perform operations on lookupKey and not on lookupKeyList
    
}

private String buildLookupKey(final List<LookUpKey> lookUpKeyList,
                              final ODPair odPair,
                              final String id) {
    lookUpKeyList.sort(Comparator.comparing(LookUpKey::getOrder));
    
    final List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    lookUpKeyList.forEach(key -> {
        switch (key.getName()) {
            case Constants.ID:
                keyList.add(id);
                break;
            case Constants.ZIP_CODE:
                keyList.add(odPair.zipCode);
                break;
            case Constants.COUNTRY_CODE:
                keyList.add(odPair.countryCode);
                break;
            default:
    
        }
    });
    
    return String.join(MiscellaneousConstants.COMMA, keyList);
}
```

Stack trace

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1262) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at com.placing.lookupKeyService.component.impl.LookupKeyComponentImpl.buildLookupKey(LookupKeyComponentImpl.java:410) ~[LookupKeyService-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.placing.lookupKeyService.component.impl.LookupKeyComponentImpl.getLookupKeyForODPair(LookupKeyComponentImpl.java:221) ~[LookupKeyService-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.placing.lookupKeyService.component.impl.LookupKeyComponentImpl.lambda$null$4(LookupKeyComponentImpl.java:196) ~[LookupKeyService-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at com.placing.lookupKeyService.component.impl.LookupKeyComponentImpl.lambda$getLookupKeyForAllConfigurations$5(LookupKeyComponentImpl.java:196) ~[LookupKeyService-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at com.placing.lookupKeyService.component.impl.LookupKeyComponentImpl.getLookupKeyForAllConfigurations(LookupKeyComponentImpl.java:185) ~[LookupKeyService-1.0.jar:?]
    at com.placing.lookupKeyService.component.impl.LookupKeyComponentImpl.lambda$getAllLookupKeys$2(LookupKeyComponentImpl.java:160) ~[LookupKeyService-1.0.jar:?]
```

Comment: A stack trace could help identifying the issue… Besides that, the temporary `ArrayList` is unnecessary. You could use a Stream operation to map the values and join them to a string in the first place. Further, it would allow to sort the stream elements without modifying the incoming `lookUpKeyList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not actually sure that it is that code which throws the exception, a stacktrace print of the exception would help in identifying the cause.
However, you mentioned a classic issue which you can face when working with `ArrayList`, expecially in a multithread environment.
In fact, it is very easy to come across a `ConcurrentModificationException`, first of all because the iterator which is created when you traverse a `java.util.ArrayList` (implicit or explicit one) adopts a "fail-fast" behaviour. This means that every time you try to modify the list while traversing it and you don't use the method `remove` or `add` defined in the iterator itself, a `ConcurrentModificationException` is immediately thrown.
For your specific case, you didn't give any much information of what happen beyond that method, but I can possibly imagine that the `lookUpKeyList` list is getting modified elsewhere by another thread, while you are traversing it in the `buildLookupKey` method when using `forEach`. 
That could explain also why the error occurs intermittently, as you may have an unpredictable situation when working on multithread environment with `ArrayList`.
That is the default behaviour of that specific list and you cannot do anything about it.
However, there are other types of lists which can help you with that, it depends on the scenario you have.
 For instance, you can use the `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`. 
I suggest that you wrap your list with a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, in this way it is guaranteed that the `ConcurrentModificationException` is never thrown, because every time an invocation of `add` , `remove` is invoked on the list, a new fresh copy of the list is created underline.
To give you an example, you should have something like that:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
...
private String buildLookupKey(final List<LookUpKey> lookUpKeyList,
                          final ODPair odPair,
                          final String id) {
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<LookUpKey> copyOflookUpKeyList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(lookUpKeyList);
     
    copyOflookUpKeyList.sort(Comparator.comparing(LookUpKey::getOrder));

    final List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>();

    copyOflookUpKeyList.forEach(key -> {
        switch (key.getName()) {
            case Constants.ID:
                keyList.add(id);
                break;
            case Constants.ZIP_CODE:
                keyList.add(odPair.zipCode);
                break;
            case Constants.COUNTRY_CODE:
                keyList.add(odPair.countryCode);
                break;
            default:

        }
    });

    return String.join(MiscellaneousConstants.COMMA, keyList);
}
```

Hope that sorts out your issue, but please let me have more info, so I can try to help you further.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco for your quick response. I have added how the method is called and the logs form the host emitted during runtime. The error does point to the buildLookupKey method only.

Comment: Yes I looked at the stack trace, it doesn't say that much, but the error is clearly caused by a modification of lookUpKeyList list while iterating through it. As I said the list might be modified by another thread, and that's the reason of the exception. Try to wrap your ArrayList with CopyOnWriteArrayList one, as I suggested above, that should solve your issue. If so and if you are happy with the answer, please accept it and upvote, so it can help other developers in the future with the same or similar issue as yours. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I'll try this and confirm if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Also the processing of the API is synchronous only so there should be single thread doing all the work here right ? Still I'll try with CopyOnWriteArrayList because I don't see any other cause

Comment: As I said, the CopyOnWriteArray is guaranteed not to throw any ConcurrentModificationException. However, if you still have issues, please add the stacktrace and the line numbers next to your code, so I can understand which call cause the error.

Comment: When you create a local copy of `lookUpKeyList`, it doesn’t have to be a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, as there is no reference to that copy outside this current method execution, so a plain `ArrayList` would do as well. The crucial aspect is the local copy, in other words, to not modify the caller provided `lookUpKeyList` and to iterate over the local copy only.

Comment: Even looking at the way the instance is obtained, it is definitely possible that different and concurrent operations might affect the `lookUpKeyList` list and that's the reason of the exception while iterating over it in `buildLookupKey` method. The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is a powerful way to use a List in a multithread access scenario, as it will never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, differently than plain `ArrayList`, which is not thread-safe. I am sure there might be different way to solve this, but in my opinion, based on my experience, I proposed a more than valid one.

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList would have definitely solved the problem, still we went with creating a local clone of the lookupKeyList because CopyOnWriteArrayList might have slowed the performance while a local clone would still allow other. threads to access that list. Thanks for the answer. Marco and @Holger

Comment: It depends on how many elements you have to deal with. If we're talking about thousands, then yes performances might be affected. Local clone? hope you didn't simply use clone() method, which creates a shallow copy and that is dangerous in concurrent scenario.